# Nginx, PHP-FPM, MySQL and Symfony using Docker : Nginx 502 Bad Gateway and Symfony No route found exception

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, nginx, docker

This post will be quite long, so make sure you have something to drink near you.

Basically, I want to use Docker to make an Nginx container, a PHP-FPM container, a MySQL container and a Symfony container which will contain the code of my Symfony app.

I've been trying to make things work for a whole week, been reading so much things, but unfortunately nothing worked.

I made a docker-compose.yml, which uses Dockerfiles for Nginx, PHP-FPM and Symfony.
MySQL is based on the image hosted on Dockerhub.

I installed everything and finally, after a week of work I still encounter two types of error :

Nginx gives me "502 Bad Getaway" randomly.
It's mainly because of a port error as if my nginx fastcgi_pass parameter wasn't set at the right value, but it is, so I don't quite understand the problem.

Then, Symfony gives me a "No route found for GET /" but I don't understand why, since the website actually works on production and for my colleagues.
I was suspicious about the database since when it's empty it could give me that error. So I took a dump from the database but it didn't give anything concluent.

Here are the files you could want

- **docker-compose.yml**

  ```
   version:'2'

  services:
    symfony:
      build: symfony/
      volumes:
        - ./symfony/code/:/var/www:rw
        - ./symfony/code/app/logs/symfony:/var/www/project/app/logs/symfony:rw
        - ./symfony/code/app/logs/nginx:/var/www/project/app/logs/nginx:rw

    nginx:
      build: nginx/
      ports:
      - 8080:80
      links:
      - fpm
      volumes_from:
      - symfony
      environment:
          <APP_SERVER_NAME>: dev-machine

    fpm:
      build: php-fpm/
      links:
      - mysql
      volumes_from:
      - symfony
      environment:
        APP_SERVER_NAME: dev-machine

    mysql:
      image: mysql
      ports:
      - 3306:3306
      volumes:
      - ./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
      - "MYSQL_USER=root"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=root"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=databaseName"
  ```
- **Nginx Dockerfile**

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:14.04

  ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  nginx

  ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

  ADD start.sh /start.sh

  EXPOSE 80

  ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
  ```
- **My nginx.conf file has this**

  ```
  proxy_buffer_size   128k;
  proxy_buffers   4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  ```
- **vhost.conf**

  ```
  server {
      listen       80;

      server_name  project.dev;
      access_log   /var/log/nginx/symfony-access.log;
      error_log    /var/log/nginx/symfony-error.log;

      #server_name  dev-machine;
      #access_log   /dev/stdout;
      #error_log    /dev/stdout info;

      root /var/www/web;
      index app_dev.php;

      location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php?$query_string;
      }

      location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
              fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
              try_files $uri =404;
              fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
              fastcgi_index app_dev.php;
      }
  }
  ```
- **PHP-FPM Dockerfile**

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:14.04

  ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      git \
      nano \
      curl \
      php5-cli \
      php5-fpm \
      php5-json \
      php5-intl \
      php5-gd \
      php5-mysql

  # Set timezone
  RUN rm /etc/localtime
  RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime
  RUN "date"

  # Install Composer
  RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
  RUN composer --version

  ADD start.sh /start.sh
  ADD symfony_environment.sh /etc/profile.d/symfony_environment.sh

  EXPOSE 9000

  WORKDIR /var/www

  ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
  ```
- **Symfony Dockerfile**

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:14.04

  ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      git \
      curl \
      php5-cli \
      php5-json \
      php5-intl \
      php5-gd

  RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

  ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
  ADD ./code /var/www
  ADD symfony_environment.sh /etc/profile.d/symfony_environment.sh

  WORKDIR /var/www

  ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
  CMD ["echo", "hello"]
  ```

I loaded the dump in the database and the `parameters.yml` is like this :

```
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
        database_host: mysql
        database_port: 3306
        database_name: <databaseName>
        database_user: root
        database_password: root
```

I really don't know what to do, any clue is welcome and I think it would be helpful for a lot of people in the future.

Comment: Well, my parameters.yml was using another parameter which tells the domain name of the website, and I needed to put the IP address of my PHP-FPM container in order to make it work. I also had to put `* @ORM\Table(name="tablename")` in lower case since the db had them in lower case and it finally works :)

Comment: good to hear that you've found it by yourself